# Find the general solution using the method of undetermined coefficients.

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $x'=$ $\begin{bmatrix}
    -1       & 1 \\
    -3       &  3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$x   + \begin{bmatrix}
    e^t \\
    1  \\
\end{bmatrix} $

Solve this using method of undetermined coefficients. I found that the eigen values are $0 ,2$ and eigenvectors are: $(1,1)$ and $(1,3)$ respectively. I am confident that that is correct. I am having trouble with my particular solution. My guess is: $x_p = ae^t +bt +c$ where $a,b,c$ are vectors. I found that $a_1=3$ and $a_2=2$ and also $b_1=b_2=-1/2$ but I can not find $c$. Is my guess wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is fine and everything is OK up to your $\vec b$ vector. I get on inserting into your equation and differentiating
$$\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-b_1+b_2\\-3b_1+3b_2\end{bmatrix}t+\begin{bmatrix}-c_1+c_2\\-3c_1+3c_2\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
And that is $4$ linearly dependent equations in $4$ unknowns.
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0&0\\3&-3&0&0\\1&0&1&-1\\0&1&3&-3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
Converting to reduced echelon from,
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac12\\-\frac12\\\frac12\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Since the fourth column isn't a pivot column, we may choose $c_2$ at will. The choice $c_2=0$ leads to $b_1=-\frac12$, $b_2=-\frac12$, $c_1=\frac12$, and $c_2=0$. So even your $\vec b$ vector was OK, you were just stuck due to interference from the eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$.